# Does helpless confer a penalty on ability checks?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

If you have to roll an ability check while at the last stage of the condition track before helpless, you take a -10. When you are helpless, do you also take this -10 on things like, say, your "not dying" check? Or does it go away to be replaced with unconsciousness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it goes away and is replaced by the unconsciousness condition.  It's unclear, however.

I'd say, from a purely **playing the game** perspective, the 'don't die' check should not have a -10.  At least for PCs and important NPCs.  They should be relatively hard to kill of blood loss.